# Capture Message output into property

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Filter a group.
2. Print the file names into a string.
3. Save the string into a property.
4. Use this property when invoking an `Exec` task.

I'm stuck at:

```
<CreateProperty Value="@(Files, ';')">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" ItemName="TSFiles" />
</CreateProperty>
<Message Text="$(TSFiles)"/>
```

Prints empty string.

---

This is what I ended up doing for now... but this almost makes me cry

```
<Target Inputs="@(DeployLabel)" Name="GenericDeploy" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFilter>%(DeployLabel.Dir)</TargetFilter>
      <TargetFilterReplaced>$(TargetFilter.Replace('\', ''))</TargetFilterReplaced>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <WriteLinesToFile
        File="$(ProjectDir)tsfiles.txt"
        Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(%(Filter),
                   '$(TargetFilterReplaced)'))"
        Lines="@(TypeScriptCompile -&gt;'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')"
        Overwrite="false" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TSFilesFiltered>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(ProjectDir)tsfiles.txt))</TSFilesFiltered>
      <TSFilesOneLine>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace(
      $(TSFilesFiltered), "[\n\r]+", " "))</TSFilesOneLine>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="tsc --target ES3 -c -d --out $(Deployroot)\foo.js $(TSFilesOneLine)" />
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)tsfiles.txt"/>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <TSFiles>@(Files)</TSFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Text="$(TSFiles)"/>
```

or just

```
<Message Text="@(Files)"/>
```

**Update:** I don't understand why you write some text into a file and directly read this file, because you call the target by each element of DeployLabel individually, so the tsfiles.txt should only include the line for the current element.

I did a test.proj here and had some issues, especially the `@(TypeScriptCompile` because the property was empty for me. So I created some dummy files with this structure:

```
d:\Temp\LabelTest\Label1.txt
d:\Temp\LabelTest2\Label2.txt
d:\Temp\LabelTest\Label2.txt
```

I made two Label2.txt for validating the Condition and found out, that it needs to be in other order. You could run it and hopefully will get some new ideas or maybe you can name what needs to be different. Here is the proj file I used for test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="GenericDeploy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

<PropertyGroup>
 <Deployroot>d:\Temp</Deployroot>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
 <DeployLabel Include="$(Deployroot)\**\Label1.txt">
  <Filter>TempLabelTest</Filter>
 </DeployLabel>
 <DeployLabel Include="$(Deployroot)\**\Label2.txt">
  <Filter>TempLabelTest2</Filter>
 </DeployLabel>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="MessageLabels">
 <Message Text="@(DeployLabel)" />
</Target>

<Target Inputs="@(DeployLabel)" Name="GenericDeploy" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy" DependsOnTargets="MessageLabels">
  <Message Text="DeployLabel.Filter: %(DeployLabel.Filter)" />
  <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFilter>%(DeployLabel.Directory)</TargetFilter>
   <TargetFilterReplaced>$(TargetFilter.Replace('\', ''))</TargetFilterReplaced>
   <ConditionTest>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(TargetFilterReplaced)', '%(DeployLabel.Filter)'))</ConditionTest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="TargetFilter: $(TargetFilter)" />
  <Message Text="TargetFilterReplaced: $(TargetFilterReplaced)" />
  <Message Text="ConditionTest: $(ConditionTest)" />

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ConditionTest)' == 'True'">
   <TSFilesFiltered>(TypeScriptCompile -&gt;'&quot;%(DeployLabel.fullpath)&quot;', ' ') </TSFilesFiltered>
   <TSFilesOneLine>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($(TSFilesFiltered), "[\n\r]+", " "))</TSFilesOneLine>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="TSFilesFiltered: $(TSFilesFiltered)" />
  <Message Text="TSFilesOneLine: $(TSFilesOneLine)" /> 

  <Message Text="tsc --target ES3 -c -d --out $(Deployroot)\foo.js $(TSFilesOneLine)" Condition="'$(ConditionTest)' == 'True'"/>
 </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have a `Condition` in `Message`, which filters the text in a special way. I need to later reuse the result of the filter in another target, so that's why none of your suggestions help, unfortunately :(

Comment: Could you post an example of your special filter condition and the usage of the result in another target?

Comment: Yup,, I can... but it is pug-ugly :( Well, I'll update the post in a few.

Comment: I will test this in a few, but to explain why I needed to write to file: if I put a condition into `Exec` task, then it will run multiple times, splitting files it needs to operate on into groups of a random size. This will result in it overwriting the target JS file several times with the arbitrary output. Writing the lines to a file and reading them back was the only way I could find to have them in a single variable (as opposed to having them filtered in the task itself).

Comment: Also, right off the bat: what you did in `ConditionTest` isn't what I was trying to do. The files need to be filtered using the metadata attached to each particular file. The way you did it, it will be "all or nothing", not the filtering.

Comment: I've posted the entire project here: http://pastebin.com/9X2SViqL in case there is something unclear about how the metadata / files are formatted.

Comment: I had a short look at it, what would you do here? `<Exec Command="tsc --target ES3 -c -d --out $(ProjectDir)deploy\tgh5-declarations @(AllTSSources -&gt;'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')"/>` Do you want to use the fullpath metadata of AllTsSources or something else? Why escaping the `->`? Don't you want to batch the call?

Comment: That one works alright. Even if it can be improved, I don't want to touch it :) I spent to much sweat and blood to get it working. The file is generated (I'm using some saner tools to compile the project, this is only for people who only know how to use MSVS... the XML writer escapes all suspicious characters). The real problem is that when `Exec` task has a condition that doesn't hold for all files in a group, it runs multiple times for sub-groups it randomly creates.

Comment: I haven't found an Exec with condition, but it could be the reason if you use different ItemGroups in that Exec task call.

Comment: Fair enough ;) there isn't one, because it wouldn't have worked if it was there. I tried that before and then changed it... because I needed it to work somehow. And, yeah, there are different groups in that task, however, the one being filtered and the metadata in condition it's being filtered on are from the same group.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce your problem, even with your code. But from my point of view the `Condition` is the problem, that didn't worked for me in all cases, that's why I "outsourced" it. Working with several `ItemGroups` at one time, I usually use a `Target with Inputs` and from there call another Target using `Properties="prop=%(OtherItemGroup->'AnyMetadata')"` and than could work it without the issues you have with ItemGroups.

Comment: Probably that would have worked too. I'll have to try it when I get to it. I just really hoped there would be a general solution. Something like in, say, Ant, you could do `<echo message="foo" property="bar"/>` and then use the property `<echo message="${bar}"/>` like that.